# Android Async Task dealing with UI 

Tags: android, android-layout, progressdialog

I am new to android development. I would like to accomplish a task described as follows:

- A main activty which calls external class(the other class would extend `AsyncTask`) to parse `xml` and receive `json` by requesting to web service and starts a `ProgressDialog`.
- The class performs `xml` and `json` parsing in its `doInBackground` method.
- In the `onPostExecute` method after parsing is complete, dismiss the `ProgressDialog` that was set in the main activity.
- I could do this by passing the ProgressDialog object to the parsing class and dismissing the same object in its `onPostExecute` method.

I think passing an instance of UI object as argument is not a good approach to program, I hope there must be some other ways to work around.

Please suggest.
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to decouple these is to use an interface:

1. Define a call-back interface (let's call it `WorkDoneListener`) with a single method: `workDone()`.
2. Declare your activity class to implement `WorkDoneListener` and implement `workDone()` to dismiss the dialog.
3. Define the AsyncTask's constructor to accept a `WorkDoneListener`. Stash the reference in a member field.
4. In `onPostExecute`, call the listener's `workDone()` method.

Comment: +1 :) in theory, he will still be, and I quote, "passing a instance" to the AsyncTask. I'm wondering if OP is under the impression it will copy the entire instance?

Comment: Good point. As in all such calls in Java, the instance won't be copied, which is both a good and a bad thing. Good because it doesn't create objects for no good reason. Bad because this could be a source of memory leaks, particularly if the async task needs to continue working in the event of a configuration change that would kill off the activity.

Comment: Yes, you will leak the original activity and all its views on an orientation switch if the reference is not cleared. You will need to handle the case when the activity is dying and detach and reattach once the activity is recreated.

Comment: Reattaching can be a problem if the reference to the async task is stored in the activity. There's a nice workaround (using a custom Application object) described in [this blog](http://www.fattybeagle.com/2011/02/14/android-asynctasks-during-a-screen-rotation-part-i/).

Answer (score 1):

Ted's answer is what you should do if your `AsyncTask` is too big and you want to declare it in other file. However, keep in mind that usually you declare the `AsyncTask` inside your UI class:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity{
    private class YourAsyncTask extends AsynkTask<etc.>{
    }
}
```

In fact, if you are using you `AsyncTask` from that activity only (I mean, if you are not using it anywhere else), declaring the `AsyncTask` as a inner class is a good design practice.